# Javascript, Razor and Escape characters. Like apostrophe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using Razor in my MVC3 project. And also I'm using FullCalendar JQuery plugin. So when I'm trying to fill the array it works good. Except one thing. If **s.Name** contains apostrophe it renders like`&#39;` that's not what I want. I tried to use different methods like Encode and Decode and even MvcHtmlString.Create and result is always the same.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            month: 5,
            year: 2011,
            editable: false,
            events: [
            @foreach (var s in ViewBag.Sessions)
            {
                @:{
                @: title: '@s.Name',
                @: start: new Date(@s.Starts.Year, @s.Starts.Month-1, @s.Starts.Day),
                @: end: new Date(@s.Ends.Year, @s.Ends.Month-1, @s.Ends.Day)
                @:},
            }
                   ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I would write your foreach like this:

```
            @foreach (var s in ViewBag.Sessions)
            { 
                <text>
                {
                 title: '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(s.Name)',
                 start: new Date(@s.Starts.Year, @s.Starts.Month-1, @s.Starts.Day),
                 end: new Date(@s.Ends.Year, @s.Ends.Month-1, @s.Ends.Day)
                },
                </text>
            }
```

- `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` to escape quotes and html markup.
- `<text>` is nicer for multiline output.

Comment: that actually worked! except that I need to take title into double quotes and prohibit using them in Sessions' names

Comment: This doesn't escape apostrophes?

Comment: Danny, see my answer for escaping/encoding.

Comment: @Fabrice Yeah, I saw it; I was just mad that the accepted answer is open to abuse ;O(

Comment: @Fabrice I've edited this answer to encode the JS, so at least people copy/pasting won't be creating poor vulnerable code :(

Comment: This will also fail if the string contains '</script>' :(

Comment: This seems to work without html.raw, so in my case, Razor: string msg = "test's"  then, onclick="confirmRun('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(msg)')"  worked fine. What is the reason for adding html.raw?

Comment: This answer shouldn't be accepted. It JavaScript-encodes but doesn't HTML-encode. `Html.Raw` should only be used with safe HTML strings.

Answer (score 87):

Here is how to do it:

```
title: '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(s.Name))'
```

Comment: very nice.  this is the way to go.

Comment: This is useful when using `'@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Resources.MyFile.ResourceName))'` with text containing HTML as the translations may contain apostrophes etc.

Comment: Doesn't this work in the incorrect order? We want decode html first and then encode the javascript string.

Comment: If you want to decode HTML, then you should use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

Comment: This will fail if the string contains '</script>' :(

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
$(function () {        
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        month: 5,
        year: 2011,
        editable: false,
        events: @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewBag.Sessions))
    });
});
```

`ViewBag.Sessions` might require some modifications to achieve the desired result (in terms of property names), which brings me to the usual remark I make about `ViewBag` when I see someone using it: using `ViewBag` is bad practice and I would recommend you using a strongly typed view with a view model.

Comment: Wow...wow... wow... that's interesting... could you please tell me how the structure (ViewBag.Session) should look? I'm no so good with javascript yet and I'm not sure how the similar structure would be look like in c# . Sorry

Comment: @Agzam, I strongly suggested you not to use `ViewBag` in your controller action. But if you insist `ViewBag.Sessions` should be an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a class with properties: `Title`, `Start` and `End`. For example: `ViewBag.Sessions = new[] { new { Title: 'foo', Start: DateTime.Now, End: DateTime.Now.AddHours(5) } };`

Comment: This will fail if the string contains '</script>' :(

Comment: @DannyTuppeny, how to reproduce your issue? The following works fine:
<script>
  @{ var text = "let's use </script>"; }
  alert('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(text))');
</script>

Comment: @Fabrice It didn't when I tried it; as the browser interpreted the </script> tag in the string as the end of the script tag (eg. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12331531/25124)). What browser did you test it in?

Comment: I don't remember.
This is too bad. I would have thought this bug had been fixed since 2012.

Answer (score 5):

`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` is not really required here.
Simply

```
 '@Html.Raw(s.Name)'
```

is worked for me.

Comment: this will fuck itself if `s.Name` contains a single quote `'`…

Answer (score 1):

You said you already tried MvcHtmlString.Create, but for me, this seems to work correctly for me:

```
'Trying @MvcHtmlString.Create("Testing'`")'
```

.

**Update:**

I took your code `&#39;`, put it in browser, copied what showed in there, put it back in Visual Studio, like:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create("'")
```

And it did work, I only got `'` back, not `&#39;`.

.

**Update 2:**

This also works:

```
@{ViewBag.Symbol = "'";}
@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.Symbol)
```

Comment: changed this:  @: title: '@s.Name', into this:  @: title: '@MvcHtmlString.Create(@s.Name)', ..... Didn't work. Renders nothing to the screen

Comment: but if I put something '@MvcHtmlString.Create("some string with a  quote ' ")' - it works.

Comment: What is the encoding of the page and of the actual string in 1s.Name`? Maybe this is the problem? Try to make sure in your browser you view the page in UTF-8 or so maybe?

Comment: so, somehow Razor doesn't wanna get this: @MvcHtmlString.Create(@s.Name). Why?

Comment: I think it is specific to your s.Name string and some culture or so you may have or the name might be encoded in.

Comment: Try with @MvcHtmlString.Create(s.Name) i.e. without the '@'

Comment: BTW, `@MvcHtmlString.Create(@s.Name)` is wrong, it should be `@MvcHtmlString.Create(s.Name)`

Comment: LOL, you said it the same time, @willvv :D

Comment: My biggest bet is on the extra `@` now. willvv seems to agree, and it actually makes sense, @Agzam, please try and tell us if it works :)