# Inline javascript with "<script>" string closes script tag by mistake

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'm inlining a large JS program, which includes a line of code like :

```
doc.write("<script>var app = \"" + _2d() + "\";</script>");
```

Unfortunately the browser (chrome) thinks the script in the string is the closing script tag, and actually takes everything after that like its HTML text.

How do I include such a string and escape it so it does not confuse the browser HTML parsing?

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but try `<\/script>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by splitting the script tag like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write) recommends:

```
doc.write("<scr"+"ipt>var app = \"" + _2d() + "\";</scr"+"ipt>");
```

Comment: Don't do that. It is slightly less efficient and significantly uglier then Kolink's solution. (And there is absolutely no need to break up the start tag)

Answer (score 23):

You should always use `<\/script>` if you want to put `</script>` in a string in JS, because `</script>` marks the end of the tag no matter where it shows up.

Comment: This!  The simple and elegant solution.