# Why doesn't HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode encode double quotes?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

In the following HTML + C# line:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Update(this, @Model.Quantity, '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(order.Notes))')">Click Me<button>
```

the `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` does not encode double quotes which breaks the function call. So, I have add `.Replace("\"","&quot;")` to it:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(order.Notes).Replace("\"","&quot;"))
```

This works but why wouldn't the utility encode a double quote? Am I using it incorrectly or is it simply created that way?

Comment: Why use Html.Raw?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know. I copied some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225796/javascript-razor-and-escape-characters-like-apostrophe) without understanding its structure and tried to use it. Removing `Html.Raw` seems to have made the utility properly escape the `"` character. I'll look into this more.